# window.getCompuedStyle doesn't work as expected?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I write following function to return the width and height of a text:

```js
function size_calculation(word,fontSize) {
  const div = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  div.textContent = word;
  div.style.cssText = `
  font-size:${fontSize}px;
  width:auto;
  position:absolute;
  visibility:hidden;
  `
  const computed_styles = window.getComputedStyle(div);
//return the expected height
console.log(computed_styles.getPropertyValue('height'))
 
  div.remove();
 
//return nothing 
console.log(computed_styles,computed_styles.getPropertyValue('height'))
 
  return ({
    height: computed_styles["height"],
    width:computed_styles["width"]
  })
}
console.log(size_calculation("hi",15))
```

I am quite confused why after I remove the `div`, all styles' property in the `computed_styles` will become `""` nothing, but before I remove the `div`, all styles' property in the `computed_styles` has something different than `""`.

In my understanding, the value for variable will not be changed and is static unless we write any update or reassign statement once declared (AM I Wrong?)

Why the  computed_styles will be automatically update?

Thank you!

P.S: not asking for solution (solution quite easy), but curious why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

> Return value: A live CSSStyleDeclaration object, which updates automatically when the element's styles are changed.

Note the word live.